# how to create a if check the whether the score of a player is 10 in python

Tags: python

```
valid_entries = ['0', '1', '2']

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter 0 for ROCK, 1 for PAPER and 2 for SCISSORS:')
    while True:
        if user_input not in valid_entries:
            print('Invalid input!')
            user_input = input('Enter 0 for ROCK, 1 for PAPER and 2 for SCISSORS:')
user_input = int(user_input)
update_scores(player_score, comp_score)
update_counts(user_input)
```

9. Write an if statement to check if the score is 10 for any of the player.

```
if com_score == 10:
    print('Computer Won')
break
    loop.
player_score == 10:
    print('You Won')
break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to check it's equal to 10 each time

```
valid_entries = ['0', '1', '2']

while True:
    user_input = input('Enter 0 for ROCK, 1 for PAPER and 2 for SCISSORS:')
    if user_input not in valid_entries:
        print('Invalid input!')
    else:
        user_input = int(user_input)
        update_scores(player_score, comp_score)
        update_counts(user_input)
        if player_score == 10:
            print("player won")
            return
```